# shiny R _ how to inseryt dataframe on a shiny interface

Tags: shiny

how can I organize my interface shiny to visualise my data by groups using fluidRow? please!

I want to imprt my data (csv) then insert my values on columns which i created on an inteface?

thank you

```
 fluidRow(
        actionButton("sauvegarder", "Sauvegarder les modifications")
      )
```